# How to mock Hibernate Query.list() using Mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

This is my class which need to be tested:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductDAOImpl.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;


@Override
public ProductDTO getProduct(String isbn) throws ProductException {
    ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
    Product product = getProductFromDb(isbn);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(product, productDTO);
    return productDTO;
}

private Product getProductFromDb(String isbn) throws ProductException{
    Session session = this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


    String hql = "FROM com.esp.dao.entity.Product P WHERE P.isbn13 = :isbn13";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("isbn13",isbn);


    List<Product> productList = query.list();  // Want to mock this call
    if(productList.size() ==1)      
        return productList.get(0);
    else if(productList.size() >1)
        // throw new ProductException("Cannot return product. Multiple products found.", HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        throw new ProductException("Cannot return product. Multiple products found.");
    else if(productList.size() == 0){
        throw new ProductException("Cannot return product. No products found.");
    }
    return null;

}
```

I want to mock the **query.list()** method. This is what I have tried so far but getting exception: **Type 'SessionFactory' is an interface and it cannot be spied on.**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestProductDaoImpl {

@Spy
private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;
@InjectMocks
private ProductDAOImpl productDAOImpl;

@Test
public void testGetProduct() throws ProductException {

    Session session = this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String hql = "";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    Query spy = Mockito.spy(query);
    List<Product> productList = getProductList();
    doReturn(productList).when(spy).list();

    productDAOImpl.getProduct("abc");


}
```

I can mock the getProductFromDb(). But in that case there is no need to write a test case for that as the maximum part of the class is getting mocked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion there are two approach:

**First:**
Create mock on SessionFactory like this

```
@Mock
private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

@Before
public void beforeTest(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testGetProduct() throws ProductException {
     //then mock all you need from hibernateSessionFactory
     Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
     Query query = Mockito.mock(Query.class);

     Mockito.when(hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
     Mockito.when(session.createQuery("FROM com.esp.dao.entity.Product P WHERE P.isbn13 = :isbn13")).thenReturn(query);

     List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(1);
     Mockito.when(query.list()).thenReturn(productList);
```

**Second:** You should create instance of SessionFactory

```
private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

@Before
public void beforeTest(){
    hibernateSessionFactory = Mockito.spy(new ConstructorForSessionFactory ());
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I just edited my question. I need to mock the Query.list() method. For that in my test class I need to create a valid Query object & then mock it. But here I am unable to mock the Query object.

Comment: @Sumit Pal. You don't have error 'Type 'SessionFactory' is an interface and it cannot be spied on' and problem with only 'query.list()'?

Comment: I have that error. By applying your solution 1 it solved & now  I am getting NullPointerException at line session.createQuery(hql);

Comment: The reason I am spying the hibernateSessionFactory is that hibernateSessionFactory is autoWired in the ProductDAOImpl. But I also need a real hibernateSessionFactory object to create Query object in the test class (so that I can mock it). Please correct me If I am wrong. I am new to Mockito

Comment: If you spying for some object you nead instance of that object another words create its manualy from constructor/factory/injector and then call spy on them.

Comment: Look at example at first solution I edit it. I wrote part chain to mock your objects up to 'List<Product> productList = query.list(); '. Also be careful that you can't mock primitive type like int and instead mocking collection better to create real collection instance

Comment: Thanks!!. I was not aware that we can mock like Mockito.mock(Session.class); I thought we have to pass a valid object of Session in Mockito.mock(). :)

Comment: Using powermockito put @PrepareForTest({Session.class}) at the top in PowerMockRunner container and then mock it.

Answer (score 1):

We can perform the unit tests for Hibernate query.list. if we have the following method to get the list of results from database:

```
private List<?> getTxns(String sql) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = ht.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Entity.class);
        return q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(sql, e);
    } finally {
        daoUtil.closeSession(sql, session);
    }

    return new ArrayList();
}
```

Then we can write the following way for unit testing :

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = mock(SessionFactory.class);
    hibernateTemplate = mock(HibernateTemplate.class);
    when(daoUtil.getWritableHT()). thenReturn(hibernateTemplate);
    when(hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory()).thenReturn(sessionFactory);
    Session session= mock(Session.class);
    when(sessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(session);
    SQLQuery sqlQuery=mock(SQLQuery.class);
    when(session.createSQLQuery(any())).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    when(sqlQuery.addEntity(Entity.class)).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    List<Entity> entityList= new ArrayList<>();
    entityList.add(txn);
    when(sqlQuery.list()).thenReturn(entityList);
}

 @Test
void getTxn_list() {
    //Arrange and Assert
    Assert.assertEquals(1,object.getTxns(query).size());

}
```